# How could I start a new community page without any predefined layout

Tags: community

How could I get rid of the predefined layout from the community template.

I choose "Partner control" theme.

The strange part of this community theme is that I can not remove the navibar on the top of the page on a custom community page.

The usability is so bad to use Salesforce lightning community.

[image: inline]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the navigation menu from e.g., the partner central template by navigating to the settings and selecting the option as highlighted in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Is there a documentation for this? I never saw this screen,,,

Comment: @PranayJaiswal - I was actually trying same thing few days back and discovered this, so was a bit fresh on this. Here's the documentation for this -- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_theme_apply.htm&type=5